# I want to delete multiple rows mysql

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I want to delete multiple rows.

Here what I am trying:

```
DELETE * FROM table_name WHERE tid = '3'
```

But it doesn't do anything.

**EDIT:**

I want to delete all rows from a table where tid = 3
I used

```
DELETE  FROM table_name WHERE tid = '3'
```

but it just remove one row.

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7406c/1)

Comment: If you need to edit question, add `EDIT` to indicate it (and try not to invalidate existting answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `*`:

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE tid = '3';
```

If `tid` is not string then `'` are not necessary.

[DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> ```
> DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
>     [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY ...]
>     [LIMIT row_count]
> ```

**EDIT:**

> *it just delete one record*

Pure guess whitespaces:

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE TRIM(tid) = '3';
```

**EDIT 2:**

Based on provided [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7406c/1) it should work.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7406c/5/1)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦═════╗
║ id  ║ productName  ║         description          ║ tid ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═════╣
║  3  ║ OpenDJ       ║ Robust LDAP server for Java  ║     ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════════════╩═════╝
```

Comment: There are multiple records with tid='3' I want to delete all these records. in your query it just delete one record

Comment: @Auj Please prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data. If tid is `string` please check that you don't have trailling/leading whitespaces

Comment: @Auj `SELECT tid, LENGTH(tid) FROM table_name WHERE  tid LIKE '%3%'`

Comment: I have added a sqlfiddle link please check.

Comment: @Auj Did you check version with `TRIM`?

Comment: lets say there are 5 record whose tid = 3 in database.
I want to delete all 5 records from database which has tid = 3

Comment: @Auj `DELETE` statement works that way. The question is: it is actually `'3'` or `' 3'`  or `'3line_feed'` or something like that.